# How do I pass a multi-dimensional array as a GET parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, header, get, multidimensional-array

I have the following code.

```
$connect  = new Connection ();
$response = $connect->putFile($fileName, $destination);
header("Location: /test.php?response=" . $response);
```

When I invoke header with the response, the file will stop execution, but I will have no error in the console... I am thinking maybe this array needs to be encoded for the url?

if that is the case how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$response` is a multi-dimensional array, you may fare best by [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php)ing it and urlencode() ing the result. It adds some overhead but not too much.

However, transporting data through GET is seriously limited. The amount of data should not exceed 1-2 kilobytes. Source: For example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

If your data is likely to exceed that limit, you should think about either transporting the data through `POST` or, if that's not possible, in a session or other kind of persistent storage.

Answer (score 2):

Use `http_build_query()`

http://us.php.net/http-build-query

Comment: I thought about using http_build_query, but the problem is that this will only turn every value of the array as get parameter. For a one dimensional array this may work well, but not for a multidimensional array, specially if the response is different every time or if it contains multiple arrays like this

[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 ()
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 ()
[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 ()
[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 ()
...